# Problem when loading large image in Samsung device(J2me game)

Tags: java, exception, java-me, midp

When i try to loading large image(1440*400)in Samsung device . Its show java error. But in nokia is run fine. The bg1.png image size is only 3kb

Sample code

```
  Image bg;

   try {

           bg=Image.createImage(("/Bg1.png"));

        } 
     catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
```

In run Method

public void run() {

```
    Graphics g=getGraphics();

    while(true)
    {

        g.drawImage(bg, 0, getHeight()-bg.getHeight(),0);
         flushGraphics();
    }
}
```

Its shows game error in Samsung.  How to fix this problem

I also trying with this example

```
Image source;
    source = Image.createImage(600,400);  
            g=getGraphics();
           bg=Image.createImage("/res/bg1.png");
```

If i make **Image.createImage(700,400)** or **Image.createImage(600,500)** Its show out of memory error in emulator also. If the value is less than or equal to **1000** means its work fine. I not understand whats the problem ?

Comment: John, what error you are getting?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace.

Comment: did you try with smaller size image? eg _144*40_? I wonder also what size file you get if you convert `Bg1.png` to plain 256-color BMP? about 500K?

Comment: yes, i tried with image size 400*320 . Its working fine . The image size is 3kb only

Comment: stack trace : java.io.IOException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main reason for the problem you describe is the limited resources of mobile devices.

If you are going to target wide range of devices, including low-end ones, you just have to learn to live with that.

For example, minimum memory requirements per MIDP 2 (JSR 118) specification are stated as follows ([source](http://leo.ugr.es/J2ME/MIDP/midpng-javadoc-final/overview.html)):

- 256 kilobytes of non-volatile memory for the MIDP implementation, beyond what's required for CLDC.
- 8 kilobytes of non-volatile memory for application-created persistent data
- 128 kilobytes of volatile memory for the Java runtime (e.g., the Java heap)

Now let's take a look at your images from that perspective. Keep in mind that in MIDP, [ARGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARGB) pixel occupies 4 bytes.

```
    Image.createImage(600,400)
```

Above gives us `600x400x4=960000` bytes, **960 kilobytes** ie well beyond above memory requirements. It would be completely legal for MIDP 2 compliant device to throw OOME for that.

Regarding [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) image file occupying 3 kilobytes, please note that PNG is a **compressed** format. Devices with insufficient processing power may need to uncompress the png image to work with it, which can inflate its size well beyond the memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

You try this one:

```
 bg=Image.createImage(("/Bg1.png")).scaled(getWidth(),getHight());
```

This is not working, You better Change the Image size for depend upon the device screen height and width.